# How i can to prevent to create multiple instance while multi request in django?

Tags: python, django

Hi everyone i have project include about payment function between user and user. But i have a problem when many user buy a product.the many payment object will created more than product avaliable. How i can to solve this ?

```
products_avaliable = Product.objects.filter(on_sell=true) 
for product in products_avaliable:
   payment = Payment()
   payment.buyer = ....
   payment.seller = product.owner
   payment.save()
   product.on_sell = False
   product.save()
```

when add deley

```
    products_avaliable = Product.objects.filter(on_sell=true)
    for product in products_avaliable:
       payment = Payment()
       payment.buyer = ....
       payment.seller = product.owner
       payment.save()


       time.sleep(10) # simulate to slow server or many request


       product.on_sell = False
       product.save()
```

when i try to time.delay before payment create (simulate when server to slow or may request by user) the payment will create many object

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the object is `on_sell` before committing to the DB:

```
for product in products_avaliable:
    payment = Payment()
    payment.buyer = ....
    payment.seller = product.owner

    product.on_sell = False

    product.refresh_from_db()  # update the object

    if product.on_sell:
        payment.save()
        product.save()
    else:
        ...
```

Comment: Thank you. But i tried It not working. I try to add time.sleep before payment.save()  payment objects create two times.